# OpenLayers 3 - getClosesPoint() of a given feature

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I viewed [this documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.geom.Point.html#getClosestPoint) and am trying to get the closest feature to a given feature like this:

```
var foo = pretendLocation.getGeometry();
console.log(getClosestPoint(foo));
```

I also tried:

```
console.log(pretendLocation.getClosestPoint());
```

`pretendLocation` is a feature I created like this,

```
var pretendLocation = new ol.Feature({
            geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([-121, 37], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'))
        });
```

Am I using `getClosestPoint()` incorrectly? What function do I use to get the closest feature to a given feature? I searched other posts but can not find a solution. I am getting console errors from both ways - getClosestPoint is not defined, as well as a cannot read property of 0 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the documentation `getClosestPoint()` is an api of `ol.geom.Point`.

So it needs to be called with geom object reference and `ol.Coordinate` to be passed to the method.
`getClosestPoint()` will find the closest point in the geometry by evaluating coordinate passed.

```
var foo = pretendLocation.getGeometry();
console.log(foo.getClosestPoint([-121, 37]));
```

`foo` is the feature's geometry .
`[-121,37]` is the `ol.Coordinate` for which closest point is searched.